# when while(sc.hasNextLine()) encounter EOF

Tags: java, io, eof

This is the program:

```
package IOReview;

import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true){
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                System.out.println("Please Input the text you want:");
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                //The while loop below  will only execute once,the rest of the program will keep running; 
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    builder.append(sc.nextLine());
                }
                System.out.println(builder.toString());
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

The second while loop will only execute once, when I input <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to terminate the sc.hasNextLine();

I want know why the sc.hasNextLine will only execute once, but the rest of the program will keep running when I input <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in my IDEA terminal.

Comment: What do you think `while (true)` does?

Comment: while(true) means the second while(sc.hasNextLine()){} will also keep running, but it only execute once ):

Comment: You terminated the standard input, so afterwards, `sc.hasNextLine()` will always be false, so that loop will not be entered anymore. A program only has one standard input, once it is closed, it remains closed.

Comment: See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571757/a-problem-i-encountered-while-using-scanner-to-receive-input?noredirect=1#comment131632944_74571757) Curiously related

Comment: What is the thread supposed to achieve here?