# A problem I encountered while using Scanner to receive input

Tags: java, windows, io

```
new Thread(() -> {
    while (true){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("请输入要输出的文本:");
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            builder.append(sc.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }
}).start();
```

I wanted to keep typing in a thread, but when I printed the string for the first time, the program didn't work the way I expected.as follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg1EP.png)
The program kept repeating, but it didn't stop for me to input.
Can you help me with this problem?

I tried to change the terminator of the input stream with an overloaded method about hasNext().

```
new Thread(() -> {
    while (true){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("enter text information:");
        while (!sc.hasNext("#")) {
            builder.append(sc.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }
}).start();
```

The results of this code are consistent with my goals,but I don't want to use another terminator instead of the default terminator. What should I do?
Please help me thank you!

Comment: *The results of this code are consistent with my goals* But you don't state what that [goal](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions)
is. One thing's for certain - you don't want to be creating a `Scanner` in a loop

Comment: Indeed, you possibly shouldn't be creating the `Scanner` in a thread at all.  Especially if the main thread is also going to be reading from standard input too.

Comment: In the seemingly related question [when while(sc.hasNextLine()) encounter EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571663/when-whilesc-hasnextline-encounter-eof) by a different author (with very similar code), the OP terminated the standard input.

Answer (score 0):

hasNextLine() method in the Scanner class returns true always since there is input all the time from the console.
Adding a condition in the while look to check if the input string is null or empty will solve this.

```
new Thread(() -> {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println("请输入要输出的文本:");

    String input;
    while ((input = sc.nextLine()) != null && !input.isEmpty()) {
        builder.append(input);
    }
    System.out.println(builder);
}).start();
```

Comment: OP is having the opposite problem.

Comment: ... and you repeat the error of opening a `Scanner` on stdin in a loop

Answer (score 0):

Imagine `hasNextLine` returns false. Then your inner while loop ends, it prints the `builder`'s contents, and.. loops, because you wrapped the whole thing in a `while (true)`. This loop makes another scanner of System.in and does the same thing - which is going to give the same result (namely: There still isn't another line). It'll return false again and voila - you get your endless loop.

I have no idea what you wanted to accomplish with the outher `while (true)` loop - you don't need 2 while loops. The outer one should just be deleted. Unless I'm missing something you intended that to do which isn't obvious from either the code or your question.

Your alternate take is 'even worse' in the sense that `.hasNext("#")` will return `true` if the user has typed `#` and then some whitespace, and false at any other time, **without consuming whatever they did type**. It'll continue to return false forever, at least, until you actually consume some tokens with some `.next()` call.

Generally, don't use the `hasX` methods. Just call the appropriate `.next` method. If you want to deal with invalid input (e.g. you ask for a `.nextInt()` and the user types 'hello' instead, or terminates the standard in stream), catch the exception and react accordingly. act-then-check-afterwards is superior to check-first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The two-tier loop is because I want to achieve the goal of receiving user input in a thread loop where each user input may have multiple lines of information.Is there a solution to the problem of always returning false on the second call to sc.hasNext()？

Comment: How would you tell the difference between one user entering a few things and the next one doing so? The computer can't differentiate one 'enter' from another, of course.